# Keeping Default UI, While Changing Certain Aspects

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I currently have a JComboBox that is always set to the bottom of the screen so the content always goes up. Seeing as I want it to go up, I would like to change the direction of the arrow on the ComboBox. I currently do that like so:

```
comboBox.setUI(new BasicComboBoxUI()
{
    @Override
    protected JButton createArrowButton() {
        return new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.NORTH);
    }
});
```

But when doing this, the ComboBox turns to a kinda grayed out version. How could I make it so it's the default ComboBoxUI, But with the arrow facing up?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source code you will see the default implementation of that method in the BasicComboBoxUI is:

```
protected JButton createArrowButton() {
    JButton button = new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.SOUTH,
                                UIManager.getColor("ComboBox.buttonBackground"),
                                UIManager.getColor("ComboBox.buttonShadow"),
                                UIManager.getColor("ComboBox.buttonDarkShadow"),
                                UIManager.getColor("ComboBox.buttonHighlight"));
    button.setName("ComboBox.arrowButton");
    return button;
}
```

Of course overriding the BasicComboBoxUI means you loose the LAF UI. For example you would loose the Windows and MAC custom LAF. You really need to override the UI for all LAF you want to support.